# Finding a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. How can I prove that $\{1,\pi,\pi^2, \ldots\}$ is a basis for this space?

Comment: The set $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\ldots\}$ is not a basis for $\mathbf{R}$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. It is a $\mathbf{Q}$-linearly independent set that cannot span $\mathbf{R}$ as a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space for cardinality reasons.

Comment: Who said this was a basis?

Comment: Yeah, probably my mistake then. BUt if this is not a basis, then does another basis exist?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html

Comment: Considering the answer is something along the lines of “you can’t” / “it’s not,” I’m wondering where this question came from?

Answer (score 9):

One may prove, using the Axiom of Choice, that a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ *exists*. However that in itself will not allow you to *write down* the elements of such a basis.

The use of the Axiom of Choice is generally thought to be essential: Under quite mild set-theoretic assumptions, there are models of standard set theory *without* the Axiom of Choice where $\mathbb R$ *does not* have a basis over $\mathbb Q$. This is the case, for example, in the [Solovay model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model). In that model all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are Lebesgue measurable, but a $\mathbb Q$-basis for $\mathbb R$ would imply the existence of a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), which cannot be measurable.

This means that a basis cannot even be *described* in terms that make sense in the absense of AC -- but that includes all notations that are usually considered to be "explicit".

Comment: Solid answer. Learned something.   +1

Comment: (Now expecting Asaf to sweep in any moment and say that the "generally thought to" hedge is unjustified here since because of such-and-such you can always have models _without_ Vitali sets but _with_ certain other unmeasurable sets).